# How to use a PS gamepad with OpenWRT?

Tags: drivers, usb, openwrt, input, games

I'm fairly new to OpenWRT and Linux in general so please bare with me.

I'm trying to print the button presses from a playstation gamepad to the console on an Arduino Yun which has OpenWRT. I've used `opkg` to install a few packages like:

```
kmod-input-core - 3.8.3-1
kmod-input-joydev - 3.8.3-1
```

And if I use `lsusb` I can see the controller:

```
root@Arduino:~# lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/004
Device: ID 054c:05c4 Sony Corp.
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x054c Sony Corp.
  idProduct          0x05c4
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Sony Computer Entertainment
  iProduct                2 Wireless Controller
  iSerial                 0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     483
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               5
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               5
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I did a quick search and most results related to accessing a gamepad from linux mention accessing through `/dev/input/js0` for example, where I only have `/dev/input/event0` which is always there, and I can see the sony gamepad under `/dev/usb/001/004` so I'm not sure if it's correctly initialized or not to begin with. Any hints/tips will be helpful.

The other issue would be accessing the keys being pressed and printing to the console. Disk space is limited on the Yun and I haven't setup an SD card yet so no gcc/g++ yet. The quickest options for now I think are using Python or shell scripts.

I've started with a little script from [this post](http://blog.flip-edesign.com/?p=62):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys


pipe = open('/dev/bus/usb/001/004','r')
#pipe = open('/dev/input/event0','r')
byte = []

while 1:
        for bit in pipe.read(1):
                byte.append('%5X' % ord(bit))
                if len(byte) == 8:
                        print byte
                        byte = []
```

Which outputs this:

```
['   12', '    1', '    2', '    0', '    0', '    0', '    0', '   40']
['    5', '   4C', '    5', '   C4', '    1', '    0', '    1', '    2']
['    0', '    1', '    9', '    2', '   29', '    0', '    1', '    1']
['    0', '   C0', '   FA', '    9', '    4', '    0', '    0', '    2']
['    3', '    0', '    0', '    0', '    9', '   21', '   11', '    1']
['    0', '    1', '   22', '   E3', '    1', '    7', '    5', '   84']
['    3', '   40', '    0', '    5', '    7', '    5', '    3', '    3']
```

and this never changes.

I've also seen a lot of examples using pygame, but I haven't managed to install pygame yet(using `opkg install python-pygame`) and until I setup an SD I won't have space for gcc/g++ to compile from source.

In short: how can I check if the gamepad is correctly installed ? If it's not, what would be the correct way to install an usb gamepad on openwrt ? What is the easiest/simplest way to print the gampad presses to console ?